# Fetching wrong data in query in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have done this

```
def show_selected_students(selected_students, students)   
    student = students.map{|a| a.name}
    selected_students = selected_students.split(",")
    @student_selected = selected_students.map {|i| student[i.to_i] }
end
```

in students I am fetching given data

```
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Student id: 1, name: "XYZ",>, #<Student id: 2,  name: "test1">, #<Student id: 3,  name: "cherry">, #<Student id: 4,  name: "mary">, #<Student id: 5,  name: "hary">, #<Student id: 35,  name: "hen">, #<Student id: 44,  name: "duck">, #<Student id: 62,  name: "try">]>
```

and in selected_students I am getting `2,3,4` Now I want to fetch those students whose id match with selected_students for this I had written this but it gives me this output `['cherry', 'mary', 'hary']` i.e id 3,4,5 but I want 2,3,4 Please guide me how to solve this. Thanx in advance.

Comment: Students "list" is always an activerecord relation? If so, you should consider using in and pluck.  students.where("id IN (?)", selected_students).pluck(:name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
def show_selected_students(selected_students, students)       
  selected_students = selected_students.split(",")
  @student_selected = students.where(:id => selected_students).map{|a|a.name}
end
```

Comment: and then use `pluck` instead of `map` to save some resources ;) (see comment to question)